# How to install the .app file in to iphone device?

Tags: iphone

I have an .app  file and the provisional profile this also contain the devices that has been bounded at the creating of this provisional profile when i use to compile it and install in the iphone via XCODE than it goes successfully in the iphone without any problem with this provisional profile.
                 But when i remove the all provisional and the app file from the iphone and pick the app file and provisional and install it via itunes through a window system it shows me the code sign error even when i sync the iphone through the itunes it get install the provisional in the iphone but unable to install the app file.

Is there any proper way via which i can install it on window or any other  OS without any fail or any tutorial ..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the app file that you are trying to install through iTunes built in Distribution configuration and using a Distribution provisioning profile? You will be able to drag, drop and install a distribution build (.app) from iTunes. However, you can install both development and distribution provisioning profiles from iTunes by dragging and dropping.

Comment: i m using development profile to install this app using itunes.

Comment: You need to build the application using distribution provisioning profile and in Distribution configuration in order to install the app through iTunes.

Comment: but i think distribution profile is used to submit the app to the app store else apple recommends to use the  developments one... 

What do you think .. ?

Comment: i think distribution one is used to submitt the app to the app store apple also recommends to test the app using the development profile 

what do you think ... ?

Comment: If you have MAC and you want to test your app on your iPhone, you can definitely build your project using development profile and run the application in debug mode on your device. If you want to provide your app file to someone else for testing, then you have the following options:
1) Ask him to give you his device, you build your app using development profile (his device UDID must have been added to the profile), connect his device to your MAC, run the app in debug mode on the device. Once the app launches, you can disconnect the device and give it over to that guy and it is fine.

Comment: 2) If that person is a developer with a MAC and XCode and you don't mind sharing your project source, he can run the application in debug mode on the device (dev profile, provided his dev certificate is present in the profile).
3) If that guy only has an iPhone and you want to send over your .app to him for testing, you would need to build your app in dist config with distribution profile (his device UDID added). He can install the .app in that case via iTunes. Distribution profile can be used this way for ad-hoc testing.

Comment: if there is an easier way of sharing pre-distribution apps without having to drag the files or any provisioning inside iTunes and synching your device. I have heard there is a new way from Apple where you can download and install these production app directly from your iDevice.                                                  if is their any way for it than tell me about it or send me sm useful link for it if u have.... Thank a lot..